# Запрос к бд с CASE в C#

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные из бд, но не работает оператор CASE, выдает вместо данных пустые ячейки. В SQLiteStudio все правильно выгружает при данном запросе. Как быть?

```
conn = new SQLiteConnection(conn_string);
conn.Open();
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
string query = "select count(id) as 'Всего заказов', case when status = 1 then count(id) else null end as 'Завершенных заказов', case when status = 1 then sum(cost) else null end as 'Прибыль' from appointment";
command.CommandText = query;

SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
conn.Close();
```

Comment: А если точку с запятой добавить в конце sql-запроса?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, здесь оно не влияет, первую колонку он считает и выводит, а вот ячейки колонок с case оставляет пустыми.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(id) as 'Всего заказов',
  sum(case when status = 1 then 1 end) as 'Завершенных заказов',
  sum(case when status = 1 then cost end) as 'Прибыль'
from appointment
```

Answer (score 0):

Заработало, когда добавил после case атрибут сравнения.

```
query = "select count(id) as 'Всего заказов', case status when status = 1 then count(id) else null end as 'Завершенных заказов', case status when status = 1 then sum(cost) else null end as 'Прибыль' from appointment";
```